# 'GameObject': no appropriate default constructor available

Tags: c++, inheritance, parent-child, default-constructor

I'm trying to create a game with GameObject being everything from tiles, player, enemy and walls. I'm trying to get my class Character (Parent to two more classes Player and Enemy) to the base class GameObject. I get the C2512 Error in the Character.cpp file when I'm trying to create the constructor for Characters. Can anyone point out what I could be doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

**Characters.h**

```
#ifndef CHARACTERS_H
#define CHARACTERS_H

#include <cstdlib>    
#include <ctime>      /*cstdlib and ctime are used to help with the pseudo randomness for events*/
#include <cstdio>   /*allows remove function*/
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "GameObject.h"

using namespace std;

class Character : public GameObject{
public:
    Character();
    ~Character();
    virtual void attack(vector<Character *>&characters) = 0;
    void set_values(string nam, int hp, int str, int mag) {
        name = nam;
        health = hp;
        strength = str;
        magic = mag;
    };
    string name;
    int health;
    int strength;
    int magic;

};


#endif
```

**GameObject.h**

```
#ifndef GAMEOBJECCT_H
#define GAMEOBJECT_H

#include "Direct3D.h"
#include "Mesh.h"
#include "InputController.h"

class GameObject {
protected:
    Vector3 m_position;
    float m_rotX, m_rotY, m_rotZ;
    float m_scaleX, m_scaleY, m_scaleZ; //Not really needed for A1.
    //Used for rendering
    Matrix m_world;
    Mesh* m_mesh;
    Texture* m_texture;
    Shader* m_shader;
    InputController* m_input; //Might have enemies who react to player input.

    float m_moveSpeed;
    float m_rotateSpeed;

public:
    //Constructor
    GameObject(Mesh* mesh, Shader* shader, InputController *input, Vector3 position, Texture* texture);
    ~GameObject();
    void Update(float timestep);
    void Render(Direct3D* renderer, Camera* cam);
```

**Characters.cpp**

```
#include "Characters.h"
#include <cstdlib>    
#include <ctime>      /*cstdlib and ctime are used to help with the pseudo randomness for events*/
#include <cstdio>   /*allows remove function*/
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void Character::attack(vector<Character *>&characters) {};

Character::Character() {

};
Character::~Character() {};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GameObject` should have a default constructor (constructor with no parameters).

Because in `Character::Character()`, compiler will generate a call to `GameObject`'s default constructor.

If you don't implement any constructor for a class `GameObject`, compiler will generate an empty default constructor for it. But you have implemented a constructor for class `GameObject`, so compiler will not do it. You should provide a default constructor for it by yourself.

Comment: Doesn't look like adding a default constructor to `GameObject` is the intent or the safe behavior here. I think R Sahu is on the money as to the intention..

Comment: Thanks that helped. I have another more easier error now which is the unresolved external symbol. That's usually when you haven't included something right?

Comment: @Zone Did you implement your new added default constructor? Because if you didn't, surely it will cause unsolved symbol error.

Comment: Oh yes, that seemed to fix it. Thank you Martin.

Comment: @Zone why implement `GameObject` at all if you are okay with a default constructor with a bunch of `nullptr`s? Or are you setting them later?

Answer (score 1):

```
Character::Character() {};
```

is equivalent to

```
Character::Character() : GameObject() {};
```

Since `GameObject` does not have a default constructor, the compiler generates an error. Unless there are sensible default values for all the arguments used by the user defined constructor of `GameObject`, you should change `Character` to have a user defined constructor that accepts all the arguments that are needed to construct a `GameObject`.

```
Character(Mesh* mesh,
          Shader* shader,
          InputController *input,
          Vector3 position,
          Texture* texture);
```

and implement it as:

```
Character::Character(Mesh* mesh,
                     Shader* shader,
                     InputController *input,
                     Vector3 position,
                     Texture* texture) : GameObject(mesh, shader, input, position, texture) {}
```